# Disable hamburger icon to arrow transition animation fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, toolbar

I replace my hamburger to custom icon but when i start a new fragment there's a default transition to hamburger to arrow icon. i would like to disable that animation.

[from hamburger to arrow [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Bk1.png)  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwbNo.png)

i'ts like this
https://media.giphy.com/media/1ffNDQPOkJ50OvGVpN/giphy.gif

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335216/transition-animation-from-hamburger-to-arrow-icon-on-adding-fragment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716854/hamburger-menu-icon-to-cross-animation-in-android

Comment: i already add the actionbardrawertoggle but still not working and i want to disable the animation.